# Drag and drop a java method from package explorer to my plugin editor

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, drag-and-drop, jface, rcp

I'm creating an eclipse plugin which has an editor. I should be able to drag classes and methods from package explorer to my editor.

I could not figure out what Transfer types I should use. Could someone please help me with this...

Thanx,
Joseph

Answer (score 0):

The package explorer provides FileTransfer (org.eclipse.swt.dnd.FileTransfer) which contains a String[] fileNames.

```
FileTransfer.getInstance();
```

You have to add an DropTargetListener to your editor and perform the operations you want.

More Information on:

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-GEF-dnd/GEF-dnd.html

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-SWT-DND/DND-in-SWT.html#_Drop_Target

http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipseDragAndDrop/article.html